# get string before last occurrence of specific character

Tags: php

Is there simple and inbuilt PHP function to remove all string after last occurrence of '/' character.
for example I have strings:

```
'js/jstree/_lib/jquery.js'
```

I want result:

```
'js/jstree/_lib'
```

Here number of slash is dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo dirname('js/jstree/_lib/jquery.js');
```

Comment: And this will amazingly break when you got `dirname('js/jstree/_lib/');` as it gives you `js/jstree`. No thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use strrpos together with substr to get the substring from the first character, up to the last occurance of the '/' character

```
$original = 'js/jstree/_lib/jquery.js';
$short = substr($original, 0, strrpos($original, '/'));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: +1, solved my problem, I have edited your answer tho, `strrpos` takes 2 arguments, not just 1.

Answer (score 1):

If it's specifically path info you're dealing with, just use `pathinfo` function:

```
$result = pathinfo($input, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
$str = 'js/jstree/_lib/jquery.js'
print_r(explode('/', $str, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'js/jstree/_lib/jquery.js';
$x = explode('/', $string, -1);
foreach($x as $y){
    $str1 .= '/'.$y;
}
echo $str1;
```